# Earth Science Search Engine

Tags: resources, informatics

After scirus is closed, which search engine do you all use?

I know of Arxiv, and ADS, which only partially overlaps with Earth Science related issues. Any other recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Would like to hear about what functionality/features of a search engine you found useful. There is an ongoing project "[EarthCube](http://www.earthcube.org/)" that is focused on managing Earth Sciences information. Communicate with [Community Inventory](http://workspace.earthcube.org/cinergi) and [Broker](http://workspace.earthcube.org/bcube) groups. I'm involved with the Inventory.

Comment: In text search of pdf / ps files, and support of search with synonyms/ equivalent wording - by that I mean, if I , e.g. write "forcasting of weather", I would appreciate if "weather prediction" is also included - that is, inclusion of other linguistic forms of search terms.

Finally, multiple languages would be great - German and English, for example would really double my field of view.

Comment: What is an Earth Science search engine?

Comment: A search engine focusing on documents / research papers in the field of earth science.

Comment: But scirus was not Earth Science specific. It searched all the ElSevier Journals or am I remembering wrongly?

Comment: Yes of course. But that was the best I had - now, I am aware, the medical students have PubMed, focusing on medicine, Jura students have thier stuff as well - now that Scirus is gone, and I need a new search enigine (google scholar is no where near scirus) I wonder if I should find one focusing on Earth Science - hence the question.

Comment: Also, i dont see a Atmospheric sciences / climatology subspace?

Comment: Scirus redirects to Science-Direct which searches the same journals. But of course that leaves away all other publishers. Google-Scholar does a pretty good job of searching all journals.

Comment: I still find Scirus used to return things which satisfied my search better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Elsevier service [Geofacets](http://www.geofacets.com/) "is designed to search for, and extract, maps, sections and other geographically-referenced geoscientific data from a very large and growing volume of published content", and as such is perhaps relevant -- though it focusses on georeferenced data rather than on scientific articles.

Answer (score 8):

I normally use [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/), but Elsevier also has the non-public [Scopus](http://www.scopus.com/) (which means I have to use a campus proxy). Also [CiteSeerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/) but the semantic side is not as rich.